# FileHelpers csv semicolon separator issue

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have this csv file :

```
    firstName;lastName;78
    fn1;ln1;67
    fn2;;56,7
    fn3;ln3;23,5
    fn4;ln4;16,7
```

And this class:

```
    [DelimitedRecord(";")]
    public partial class Person
    {
        private string firstName;

        [FieldNullValue("default first name")]
        private string lastName;     

        private string age;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }

        public string Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
    }
```

And i use this code to retrieve the data:

```
            ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(Person));
            provider.FileName = "data.csv";
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = provider.ExtractRecordsAsDT();
```

And the data table contains this:

```
dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray
{object[3]}
    [0]: "firstName;lastName;78"
    [1]: "default first name"
    [2]: {}
dataTable.Rows[1].ItemArray
{object[3]}
    [0]: "fn1;ln1;67"
    [1]: "default first name"
    [2]: {}
dataTable.Rows[2].ItemArray
{object[3]}
    [0]: "fn2;;56"
    [1]: "7"
    [2]: {}
dataTable.Rows[3].ItemArray
{object[3]}
    [0]: "fn3;ln3;23"
    [1]: "5"
    [2]: {}
dataTable.Rows[4].ItemArray
{object[3]}
    [0]: "fn4;ln4;16"
    [1]: "7"
    [2]: {}
```

I am definitely missing something.

EDIT: I replaced decimal separator from ',' to '.' and i still get the same bad results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved : FileHelperEngine must be used instead of ExcelStorage